# Ubuntu 20.04 boot problem

Tags: boot

I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 in an Acer Extensia laptop. At first the USB installer failed to recognize the hard disk, but on closing the lid and reopening, I could do an install, deleting Windows. Now the boot from the hard disk stops at the initramfs prompt. Here's a photo:[initramfs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHgfA.jpg)

I've made somewhat extensive research but none of the proposed solutions work.

Would be much obliged if someone suggests a solution

Comment: When I tried to add a picture to my original question it says can't be done if I don't have enough reputations

Comment: ls /dev/sd* in Ash shell returns "No such file or directory" so hard disk not mounted

Comment: You don not need a picture nor should you have pictures of text. Cut and paste text.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like partitions were not created properly during the installation. If you can use the installation medium to run a live system, then boot into live system and run the following commands to provide us with a bit more information.

```
sudo blkid
lsblk
sudo fdisk
```

Comment: So /dev/sda is your 16G USB and /dev/sdb is your HD. As one can from the original photo of initramfs see, during the boot process, your HD can not be found or mounted for some reason...

Comment: as you are able to run Ash shell... can you try `ls /dev/sd*` if your HD becomes later available?